# Adding custom request header

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, spring-mvc, xmlhttprequest

I have an API. I'm trying to send a request to my api with Ajax Jquery but having problem. Below is my Ajax request. I'm sending data in JSON format, plus I need to add two request headers(signedInUserId & accessToken). But this is not working.

```
  $.ajax( {
                        type: "PUT",
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("signedInUserId", "1");
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("accessToken", "testtoken");
                          },
                        url: "url to my api",
                        data: JSON.stringify(data), 
                        success: function( response ) { 
                                 // $('#successMessage').html(response);
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            //message
           }
                    });
```

Although, if I send request without custom headers(signedInUserId & accessToken) and in my api controller I comment the custom header parameters, its working absolutely fine. Below is my api controller code.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "test.json", method = { PUT })
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, ? extends Object> test(HttpSession session, @RequestHeader Integer signedInUserId, @RequestHeader String accessToken, @RequestBody MyTestModel myTestModel) {

// working

}
```

I'm confused why it isn't working when I send custom headers, is there some problem in sending the custom headers?

EDIT:
Below are my request and response headers.

```
       Request URL:http URL....
       Request Method:OPTIONS
       Status Code:200 OK
       Request Headersview parsed
       OPTIONS /Url/url/add.json HTTP/1.1
       Host: local host:8080
       Connection: keep-alive
       Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
       Origin:url
       User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
       Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, accesstoken, signedinuserid, content-       type
       Accept: */*
       Referer: url
       Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
       Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
       Response Headersview parsed
       HTTP/1.1 200 OK
       Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
       Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
       Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, DELETE
       Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, x-requested-with
       Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
       Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
       Content-Length: 0
       Date: Sun, 03 Nov 2013 19:11:20 GMT
```

Comment: what's not working....inspect request in browser console to see status, what is sent (including headers), returned etc. Need to isolate client vs server when troubleshooting ajax

Comment: Well on Firefox, it just handshake and doesn't send PUT request after that and return no errors/response.

On Chrome I'm getting this error:
" Request header field accessToken is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."

Comment: so in your network tab you see nothing at all pointing at the url  set in ajax?

Comment: updated my question with header and response. When I press button, I can see it requesting to the url but the requests gets failed/cancelled and shows up this error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/test/quote/add.json. Request header field accessToken is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."

Comment: This is happening in chrome ^

But in firefox it doesn't do any thing after OPTION requets.

Comment: well...what turned up when you searched that term on web? Is a big clue to start with. MDN Docs are great resource to search also

Comment: have you tried using POST?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just resolved the issue. Will update it in my answer soon.

Comment: add a comment when you update...curious what it was. Guessing a server ini, or htaccess problem

Comment: Well apparently the problem was due to allowed headers in server response. In the my server setting the allowed header in response were as follows: 
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-requested-with");
So, I added two more header accessToken and signedInUserId in allowed headers.
And I guess that was the issue why the request wasn't going beyond preflight request (OPTION) as the header I was sending wasn't allowed in response headers sent by server.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well apparently the problem was due to allowed headers in server response. In the my server setting the allowed header in response were as follows:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-requested-with");
```

So, I added two more header accessToken and signedInUserId in allowed headers, and the response headers now looks like below:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, accessToken, signedInUserId, x-requested-with");
```

And I guess that was the issue why the request wasn't going beyond preflight request (OPTION) as the header I was sending wasn't allowed in response headers sent by server. Please correct me if I'm wrong.